# What is the event handler equivilent to the LINQ code used here

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have seen several tutorials about MVVW but I am still unsure.

On this [website](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/). As a result I have implemented the method it provided:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace OCLMEditor
{
    public class DelegateCommand<T> : System.Windows.Input.ICommand
    {
        private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action<T> _execute;

        public DelegateCommand(Action<T> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public DelegateCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_canExecute == null)
                return true;

            return _canExecute((parameter == null) ? default(T) : (T)Convert.ChangeType(parameter, typeof(T)));
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute((parameter == null) ? default(T) : (T)Convert.ChangeType(parameter, typeof(T)));
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

And at the moment, in my ViewModel I have this:

```
public class OCLMEditorModelView
{
    private readonly DelegateCommand<string> _DeleteStudentButtonClickCommand;

    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get
        {
            return _Model.Students;
        }
    }

    private Student _SelectedStudentItem;
    public Student SelectedStudentItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedStudentItem; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedStudentItem = value;
            _DeleteStudentButtonClickCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    private OCLMEditorModel _Model;

    public List<StudyPointItem> ReadingStudyPointsList { get; set; }
    public List<StudyPointItem> StudentStudyPointsList { get; set; }
    public List<String> TreasureItemMethodsList { get; set; }

    public OCLMEditorModelView()
    {
        InitTreasureItemMethodsList();
        InitReadingStudyPointsList();
        InitStudentStudyPointsList();

        _Model = new OCLMEditorModel();

        _DeleteStudentButtonClickCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(
            (s) => { _Model.Students.Remove(_SelectedStudentItem); _Model.Serialize(); MessageBox.Show("Student deleted!"); }, //Execute
            (s) => { return _SelectedStudentItem != null; } //CanExecute
            );
    }

    public DelegateCommand<string> DeleteStudentButtonClickCommand
    {
        get { return _DeleteStudentButtonClickCommand; }
    }

    // Code snipped
}
```

For completeness, the XAML for the button:

```
<Button x:Name="buttonDeleteStudent" 
        Content="Delete" 
        Margin="2" 
        Command="{Binding DeleteStudentButtonClickCommand}"/>
```

It all works fine. But I find this code diffcult to read (LINQ):

```
 _DeleteStudentButtonClickCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(
    (s) => { _Model.Students.Remove(_SelectedStudentItem); _Model.Serialize(); MessageBox.Show("Student deleted!"); }, //Execute
    (s) => { return _SelectedStudentItem != null; } //CanExecute
    );
```

I know what it is doing. But if my code gets more complex I would prefer a dedicated handler. How do I define this handler?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, this is not linq, it's just lambda methods passed as parameters.

If you want to stick with the DelegateCommand class the alternative is to define methods instead of passing lambdas as by replacing :

```
public OCLMEditorModelView()
{
    InitTreasureItemMethodsList();
    InitReadingStudyPointsList();
    InitStudentStudyPointsList();

    _Model = new OCLMEditorModel();

    _DeleteStudentButtonClickCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(
        (s) => { _Model.Students.Remove(_SelectedStudentItem); _Model.Serialize(); MessageBox.Show("Student deleted!"); }, //Execute
        (s) => { return _SelectedStudentItem != null; } //CanExecute
        );
}
```

with

```
public OCLMEditorModelView()
{
    InitTreasureItemMethodsList();
    InitReadingStudyPointsList();
    InitStudentStudyPointsList();

    _Model = new OCLMEditorModel();

    _DeleteStudentButtonClickCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(
        ExecuteMethod, //Execute
        CanExecuteMethod//CanExecute
        );
}

void ExecuteMethod(string s)
{
    _Model.Students.Remove(_SelectedStudentItem); 
    _Model.Serialize(); 
    MessageBox.Show("Student deleted!"); 
}

bool CanExecuteMethod(string s)
{
    return _SelectedStudentItem != null;
}
```

Note that this really doesn't add any maintainability, quite the contrary, this is a good thing to do if you reuse those methods code elsewhere but the point of defining methods inline with Anonymous methods or lambda syntax is to have the code displayed where it is used which is great for small non reusable snippets. Also note that in your lambda syntax version the CanExecute could be simplified (single statement, can remove the bracers and return) and there is no reason to write everything in a single line (so in the Execute each statement could be on it's own line). I'd rewrite it as such :

```
public OCLMEditorModelView()
{
InitTreasureItemMethodsList();
InitReadingStudyPointsList();
InitStudentStudyPointsList();

_Model = new OCLMEditorModel();

_DeleteStudentButtonClickCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(
    (s) => 
        { 
            _Model.Students.Remove(_SelectedStudentItem); 
            _Model.Serialize(); 
            MessageBox.Show("Student deleted!"); 
        },
    (s) => _SelectedStudentItem != null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and advice!